# Не помогает try cath при использовании модуля fs в node. Возникает ошибка - Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Почему не помогает try cath в этом случае? Есть варианты как быть?
Вот такая ошибка возникает:

```
[Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'] {
  errno: -4082,
  code: 'EBUSY',
  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: 'C:\\hiberfil.sys'
}
```

Вот такой код:

```js
async function getStatusDirectory() {

  try {
    const path = 'C:/'
    const dirIterable = await fs.promises.opendir(path);
    let dir = []
    for await (const dirent of dirIterable) {
      dir.push({ ...dirent });
    }
    console.log(dir)
    let promises = await Promise.all(dir.map(dir => {
      let promise
      try {
        promise = fs.promises.lstat(path + dir.name)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        promise = { locked: true }
      } finally {
        return promise
      }
    }))
    console.log(promises)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

}
getStatusDirectory()
```

[image: скриншот консоли]

Comment: `promise = fs.promises.lstat(path + dir.name)`  тут `await`пропущен

Comment: Ну и вообще, а надо ли тут заморачиваться асинхронностью? Может проще использовать синхронные версии функций?

Comment: Вообще если это запустить в другой директории, то все работает. Проблема возникает когда программа пытается получить сведения "hiberfil.sys". Добавил скриншот.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать `Promise.allSettled()`

```
async function getStatusDirectory() {

  try {
    const path = 'C:/'
    const dirIterable = await fs.promises.opendir(path);
    let dir = []
    for await (const dirent of dirIterable) {
      dir.push({ ...dirent });
    }
    console.log(dir)
    let promises = await Promise.allSettled(dir.map(dir => {
      return fs.promises.lstat(path + dir.name)
    }))
    console.log(promises)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

}
getStatusDirectory()
```